# Various CUDA dll files not found when trying to use GPU for Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

When trying to use the NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit with Tensorflow/Anaconda, I am running into the issue of various dll files missing after CUDA installation. This is what TF complains about:

```
2021-06-13 15:57:48.349493: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2021-06-13 15:57:48.349942: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2021-06-13 15:57:48.350349: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2021-06-13 15:57:48.350752: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2021-06-13 15:57:48.351155: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2021-06-13 15:57:48.351555: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
```

Initially, cudart64_110.dll was missing as well, but I manually downloaded it and placed it into C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin .
It is not an issue of Environment Variables (i.e. path) - the above DLLs are simply not available after installation of CUDA, neither in the above toolkit folder, nor anywhere else.
I can't simply install a prior version of CUDA either, as the installation tool mentions that I have a newer version installed already.

What am I missing in terms of these DLLs not being available?

Comment: The tensorflow build you have requires CUDA 11.0. No other version will work.

Comment: Tensorflow is very sensitive about being compiled with the correct version of CUDA, the chart at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows should be followed strictly

Comment: Thank you both - that was the reason it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

TF needed CUDA 11.0, as was kindly pointed out in the comments. Weirdly enough, my RTX 3070 performs significantly worse than my i9-10850K (training a dense sequential model with a batch size of 128), but that is a separate topic I need to look into.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be the issue- startup and loading works fine. It's the actual training process that's slower: For example, training the same model on the same data with my i9: 3 seconds per epoch. On my RTX 3070: 7 seconds per epoch (tried batch size 256 just now). This doesn't change over several hours of usage